# How to create JRE to run jar programs?

Tags: java, maven, executable-jar, jlink

I have an **executable-jar** that I can run with **java -jar app.jar** but the **SDK is 326MB**. This is a lot.

jlink can create a **JRE**, but I can't use **jlink** as I have a **non-modular application**.

Can you please tell me how to create a JRE?

Comment: You have an JRE ... as you already mentioned your app is not modular so you can't use jlink to create a custom JRE...

Comment: @khmarbaise so I have to use JDK instead of JRE, which weighs 326mb? I can't find JRE 18.0.1

Comment: You can try this: https://javaalmanac.io/ there are links to JRE's.. but reconsider upgrading to JDK19 because sind 20.09 JDK19 is the current release...

Comment: @khmarbaise, thanks a lot! I found JRE 80mb there, with which my application started

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is answered by comments

Comment: “I can't use jlink as I have a non-modular application.”  Why not write a module-info.java, then?  As long as you’re not using illicit hacks of Java SE classes, it should work just fine.

Comment: @VGR I've been trying to make the app modular for over a month, but there have been an endless amount of bugs and incompatibilities since the libraries are big. I would be happy to have everything work by itself with the help of jlink.

Comment: @VGR using module-info for creating a customized JRE is not enough. That means all of your deps must be modules as well and having jmod files as well. etc.. That's not the easy..

Comment: Perhaps [*jpackage*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/jpackage/packaging-overview.html) is useful, I don't know. Console documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/specs/man/jpackage.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`jlink` can be used to create a 'JRE'/runtime image for non-modular applications just fine. It just can't automatically derive the modules that should go in the runtime image in that case. They have to be specified manually instead.

For instance, if I have a simple `app.jar`:

```
$ java -jar app.jar
Hello World!
```

Then create a runtime image with `jlink`, with only the `java.base` module:

```
jlink --output runtime --add-modules java.base --strip-debug --no-header-files --no-man-pages
```

Then I can run the jar with the `java` executable in the runtime image:

```
$ ./runtime/bin/java -jar app.jar
Hello World!
```

And the runtime image is just ~35 MB (though this can vary per platform).

---

`jdeps` can be used to get an idea of which modules should be used to create the runtime image:

```
$ jdeps --print-module-deps add.jar
java.base
```

This will print a comma-separated list of modules that can be passed directly as an argument to the `--add-modules` option of `jlink`. (though, service interface implementations have to be handled separately. See e.g.: [jdeps does not add jdk.random when using RandomGenerator.getDefault()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75201154))

Answer (score 1):

You can try to this as source:

https://javaalmanac.io/

where you can find links to download only JRE instead of JDK.