# jdeps does not add jdk.random when using RandomGenerator.getDefault()

Tags: java, java-17, jlink, jdeps

I have a Java 17 application which uses `RandomGenerator.getDefault()` in it. When I use jdeps to create a minified JRE for it, it does not add `jdk.random`, so the JRE created by jlink cannot run the application. Is there something I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `RandomGenerator` interface is in the module `java.base`, which can not depend on any other module, including `jdk.random`.

Instead it uses the [`ServiceLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) API to find implementations of `RandomGenerator`. The `jdk.random` module provides several implementations of the `RandomGenerator` interface:

```
> java --describe-module jdk.random
jdk.random@19
...
provides java.util.random.RandomGenerator with jdk.random.L32X64MixRandom jdk.random.L64X128MixRandom jdk.random.L64X128StarStarRandom jdk.random.L64X256MixRandom jdk.random.L64X1024MixRandom jdk.random.L128X128MixRandom jdk.random.L128X256MixRandom jdk.random.L128X1024MixRandom jdk.random.Xoroshiro128PlusPlus jdk.random.Xoshiro256PlusPlus
...
```

However, since there is no explicit dependency from `java.base` to `jdk.random`, it is not included automatically when you include `java.base`.

Modules that implement services have to be included manually using `--add-modules` when running `jlink` instead.

You can use `jlink`'s `--suggest-providers` option to get a list of modules that implement a service:

```
> jlink --suggest-providers java.util.random.RandomGenerator

Suggested providers:
  java.base provides java.util.random.RandomGenerator used by java.base
  jdk.random provides java.util.random.RandomGenerator used by java.base
```

(There's also the `--bind-services` flag, but that will include *ALL* service implementations, which is probably not what you want)